# Static Variable with null reference

Tags: java, static, static-variables

When I run this code it print twice 0  but i don't undrestand why after affect the object k to null the value of count still printed 0 but when i delete  static  before count  and execute this program it print first 0 and then i  print an exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. 
Please Can you resolve this problem.

```
public class Test{
    public static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.count); // 0
        t=null;
        System.out.println(t.count); // 0
    }
}
```

Comment: how does this code compile?

Comment: Typo mistake @Carcigenicate

Comment: If the variable is static than it doesn't need an instance. This goes to the very definition of the concept of static.

Comment: *If* `t.count` still works after making `t` `null` it's because it's able to infer the type and lookup `count` as a static variable. If you make `count` non-static though, it ceases to exist (or at least can't be referenced) once `t` is `null`. I would expect both to cause NPEs, but I also rarely use static variables, and when I do, I don't access them via instances. You should be using `Test.count` to reference it.

Answer (score 2):

`static` variables in Java are defined at class level and you do not need an object of that class to reference static variable.
And even if you write `t.count` JVM will instead do conventional `Test.count` instead (it will replace name of variable with name of its class).

And below extract from JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1

> Example 15.11.1-2. Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field
>   Access
>
> The following program demonstrates that a null reference may be used
>   to access a class (static) variable without causing an exception:
>
> class Test3 {
>       static String mountain = "Chocorua";
>       static Test3 favorite(){
>           System.out.print("Mount ");
>           return null;
>       }
>       public static void main(String[] args) {
>           System.out.println(favorite().mountain);
>       } } It compiles, executes, and prints:
>
> Mount Chocorua Even though the result of favorite() is null, a
>   NullPointerException is not thrown. That "Mount " is printed
>   demonstrates that the Primary expression is indeed fully evaluated at
>   run time, despite the fact that only its type, not its value, is used
>   to determine which field to access (because the field mountain is
>   static).

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you meant `t=null;` instead of `k=null;`.

The static variables are there always only once in whole program, they aren't bent to the objects. All instances of Test have the same count, always. If you set it to anything else, it will change for all instances. Therefore, you can read the value from null as well. Alternativelly, you can use `System.out.println(Test::count)`, which will also print 0, without the need of any object of class Test.